# javaFx—GridPane can delete node by inputing rowindex and coloumnindex

Tags: javafx, gridpane

I don't want to use remove in this code

```
chessPane.getChildren().removeAll(piece[0][chessPane.getRowIndex(piece[0][6].getImageView())-2].getImageView(), piece[0][chessPane.getRowIndex(piece[0][6].getImageView()) - 1].getImageView());
```

anyone can provide a better solution to delete this node?

Comment: No. To remove a node from a parant, you need to remove it from the parent's child list.

Comment: OK  thank u very much